# SQL Server table indexing for specific LINQ for SQL query

Tags: sql-server, performance, linq-to-sql

I'll be describing the business case first.  If you just want the question, please skip a couple of paragraphs ahead...

I'm synchronizing data on a .NET mobile client from an ASP.NET Web API server over the Web.  Due to "mobile nature" of the client, I'd like the process to be as efficient as possible, so I'd like to implement an incremental synchronization, meaning that the client asks for new entries from a specified date, which will usually be the last sync date.

I'm dealing with entry deletions separately, so for the sake of simplicity, let's focus on new and modified entries.

The table being synchronized is too large to fit in a single response, so paging is implemented.

Each entry in the table has a unique ID **column** and a **LastUpdated** column.  On the server, I'm using the following code to respond with the requested page:

```
var set             = Model.Set<T>().Where(t => String.Compare(t.LastUpdated, fromDate, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0).OrderBy(t => t.Id);
var queryResultPage = set.Skip(pageSize * pageNumber).Take(pageSize);

return queryResultPage.ToList();
```

Model.Set is the DbSet from which data is retrieved.  Please ignore the fact that I must use strings to represent dates...

My question is, what SQL Server table index(es) would produce optimal performance *for this case*?

Comment: this is not really a linq-to-sql question but more SQL server. Profile the SQL, enter it in SQL management studio and examine the query plan. This will give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleun is exactly right.  I did a demo of this for a client recently on the CRM 2011 platform.  I showed them a case where a page view was taking ~30 seconds to load a page after sorting through 2.2M records plus an additional 4.5M records.

Using SQL Profiler, you can find the query being run.
Put it into SQL Management Studio (clean it up as necessary to make it standard SQL)
Then run execution plan and look for indexes it suggests (especially ones it says are missing)

Anyway, in my demo to my client, after we finished with this, the query dropped down to less than a second; and the page loaded in about 4 seconds (which is still pitiful).

Comment: Thanks Pleun and Mike.  Nice to know you can profile LINQ2SQL.  I've found a lovely tool called LINQPad which shows the resulting SQL, which I copied to SSMS and viewed the estimated execution plan.  I also traced the query in SQL Server profiler.  So I'm at that "good starting point", but what's next?  Where can I find the suggested indexes?

Comment: if the execution plans finds that a non-existing index would speed up the performance, it will appear as a line of green text above the execution plan.  If there's no green text, there either is no suggestion or else you've done it wrong =/